# iOSApp crash when shared via testflight with COSMCtrl _foregroundAppActivity incoming bundle has nil supplied UUID, finds existing error in devicelog

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

iOSApp crash when shared via testflight with "**COSMCtrl _foregroundAppActivity incoming bundle  has nil supplied UUID, finds existing** " error symptomsd in devicelog App works fine if distributed via AppCenter that uses AdHoc profile.

- App only crashing when distributed via testflight but it works fine when shared with appcenter or in debug mode.
- App is not crashing at launch time, it crashes after one screen so I think it may not be related to app signing certificate Dev
- CPU spike is there on that event but its not that much its only 12 to 20% when checked in debug mode.
- Yes I am doning some API hit at that point and parsing response JSON.

[image]

Any clue or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: COSMCtrl sounds like it's a 3p library and it looks like it's crashing there. Have you tried looking through their documentation? If it's only crashing on a specific screen it should be easy enough to track down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced the same issue and I found that i have updated the UI in background thread. Fix of this is I Updated the UI in Main thread and issue was fixed. I hope it will help you!

Comment: Thanks for the Hint, there was some UI action that was not on the main thread, fixed that and it worked fine. The app was only crashing on prod mode in testfligt so was no way to debug.